# Navigation Drop down postioning

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu

When hovering over "Arts District" and "Property Management" on my site navigation, I need the dropdown position of the sub menu item to be relative to the parent item, seen when you hover over "The Bulding" in this jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/8Wce6/1/

What is the best way to do this? Do I need to create ul id's for each dropdown? Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make the parent li's relatively positioned and floated. Then the child ul's absolutely positioned with value of "left:0"

[JSFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/8Wce6/3/)